# View inside other view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In a Rails application I have a view index.html.erb and a controller posts_controller.rb.
In the controller I have defined a variable:

```
def index
@posts = TableName.find...
```

and in the view I have:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

If I access it via localhost/posts/index it works fine. But what I really want is to show this view inside other views so I'm using `<%= render :template => 'posts/index' %>` but I get this error message: "NoMethodError -  You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.each"

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

NoMethodError is triggered when you try to call methods on undefined object. In other word, you render posts/index in other views, but @posts instance variable is not defined in the other view. render template does not route the controller.

Comment: I already knew that. What I want to know is how should I do. Thanks

Comment: You have to define `@posts` in every controller action that renders a template that has your `posts/index` template.

Comment: Isn't there a better option to display a view inside another? Thanks